# Unable to set VueJs Component data values from component prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For some reason, the value for `customer_data.customerReference` is never available yet I can see using Chrome debugging tools that the data exists in the prop and is successfully passed from my app down to the component.

```
Vue.component("mycomponent", {
    template: '#my-component-template',
    props: ["customer_data"],
    data() {
        return {
              myData: 'This works fine!',
            form_data: {
                customerRef: this.customer_data.customerReference
            }
    }
}
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            customer: {
                customerReference: 007
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Here is my markup including the template:

```
<div id="app">
    <mycomponent customer_data="customer" />
</div>

<script type="x-template" id="my-component-template">
    <div>
        <p>{{form_data.customerRef}}</p>
        <p>{{myData}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Please see the following JsFiddle with a simplified example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ProNotion/a8c6nqsg/20/

What is that I am missing here or implementing incorrectly?

Comment: v-bind:customer_data="customer", without v-bind, you're just passing down the string 'customer'

Answer (score 2):

You should bind it using `v-bind:` or just `:`

```
   <div id="app">
      <mycomponent :customer_data="customer" />
    </div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: In this case, you are correct, a typo in my example however in my app for some reason the issue persists. I will need to try and replicate the issue in my JsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a string that says 'customer' and not the actual customer object. All you need to do is change `customer_data="customer"` to `v-bind:customer_data="customer"`